# Remove special character from csv file using bash

Tags: bash

I have csv file in which the first([) and second last column (]) contain special character. An example is given below

```
col1      col2      col3      ..... coln-1   coln  
[number   number    number    ..... number]  number
```

I want to remove `[` from first and `]` from second last column using bash script

with this `sed 's/]//g' file`, I can remove `]`. However I have error for `[` with same statement.

Comment: I am trying to see if I can use `sed` command.

Comment: ok then, Show your `sed` command in question.

Comment: with this `sed 's/]//g' file`, I can remove `]`. However I have error for `[` with same statement. @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with `sed` is sound.  You just need to know that `[` and `]` are special characters in (all flavors of) regular expressions, therefore they need escaping with backslashes.  And to name a choice of two characters, `[…]` is used, so:

```
sed 's/[\[\]]//g' test.csv
```

This, however, can be done quicker using `tr` which can remove given characters:

```
tr -d '[]' < test.csv > test2.csv
```

Comment: my approach with `sed` is sound however I got negative vote for my question. confusing. @Alfe

Comment: Originally, you didn't show any efforts of solving it by yourself, no code, whatever.  So someone downvoted.  Later you added comment with a piece of code but didn't change your question.  Downvotes cannot be revoked after some time unless the question has been changed.  You should have given the `sed` approach in the question instead of in a comment.

Comment: Let's hope the downvoter sees and revokes the downvote (but don't be too sad if this doesn't happen, the one in question probably moved on already). (@anubhava?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sed -i -e 's/^\[\(.*\)\] \(-?[0-9\.]*\)$/\1 \2/g' $file
            ^ ^^ ^^    ^  ^   ^        ^  ^  ^ 
            | || ||    |  |   |        |  |  + -the second match (the number)  
            | || ||    |  |   |        | +---- the first match (the n-1 first fields)      
            | || ||    |  |   |        +------ end of line
            | || ||    |  |   +--------------- a number
            | || ||    |  +------------------- save in memory (\2)
            | || ||    +---------------------- your closing bracket
            | || |+-------------------------- the n-1 first fields
            | || +--------------------------- save in memory (\1)
            | |+----------------------------- your opening bracket
            | +------------------------------ beginning of line    
            +-------------------------------- substitution mode
```

What it means, in English, is "perform a substituion, replace lines that begin with a [, contain a bunch of things (and remember them), have a ] after that, and a number afterwards (remember it) by the first bunch of things and the number."

The `-e` means "perform some regexp operation", and the `-i` means "overwrite the input file with the output of the command".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk  '{gsub(/[][]/,"",$1); gsub(/[][]/,"",$(NF-1))} 1' file
```

Or `sed` but that will not be limited to the first or second to last column:

```
sed -e 's/[][]//g' file
```

The key is the regex `[][]` where if you have the closing `]` immediately after the opening `[` it is considered to be part of the character class rather than a regex meta character.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/[\[\]]/,"")}1' file

col1      col2      col3      ..... coln-1   coln  
number   number    number    ..... number  number
```